# Dell Vastro 3550 laptop keyboard is not working

Tags: keyboard

Dell Vastro 3550 laptop keyboard is not working, after replacing the motherboard. 
I have checked with the external keyboard and it worked initialy but when windows 7 loaded it stoped working as well. Any one has idea about it, how to fix this problem? Please

Answer (score 1):

Since you replaced the mobo, go back and re-check your work, maybe the keyboard ribbon cable did not get connected properly.